# database creation from multiple spreadsheets that keeps updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet template that contains 3 sheets, for 3 types of tasks made for a client (let's call the sheets "task1", "task2" and "task3").

- Each client ("client1", "client2"...) has his own spreadsheet made from this template.
- Each of the sheets for each client is being constantly updated everytime a new task is made in a new row that contains its' details.
- New clients (=new spreadsheats) might be added.

I would like to create a "tasks documentation master" - a database that will hold, in 3 sheets ("task1 master, "task2 master", "task3 master"), **all** rows from all sheets for all clients.

1. How can I make it dynamic to keep updating with all data in all spreadsheats (blank rows should not be updated in the database)?
2. How can the syncing range be defined (for example - only sync fro, row 4 and up to column O)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently creating a library which allow you to use Gsheet as SQL dB. I'll let you know once published

Comment: Sounds awesome, thank you.

Comment: I think this can also be easily achieved via `IMPORTRANGE` & `QUERY` formulas. If you could potentially share some dummy sheets with the expected output, I should be able to help :)

Comment: Sure Sourabh, thanks!

Comment: master: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJUSV9H_yqDoi4D-qFLZUC3OIxGNWEsz6DOd2i-hUAA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: client 1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19jWXzEovqir_Ok4ZQytc_ACxhZSY55BtghKcj5NoBf4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: client 2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11hDl-w__RCxlfWh6_Qp8WCJHS8tVSYwba_N_VvfaeRM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: client 3: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uoh-aBTOA7abk-kmOUZ8P2HV7uSDUnak2_cjuwRumd8/edit#gid=0

Comment: You want to update the master spreadsheet every time someone complete a new row in any of the client sheets right?

Comment: Yes Andres, exactly. Update the master sheet in the master spreadsheet on updates on a respective sheets in the clients spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the methods for the Spreadsheet Service [1] and installing an onEdit trigger to each of the clients Spreadsheets [2], I achieved the process you want with the following code:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  //Get edited client row and Sheet  
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editedRow = editedCell.getRow();
  var clientSheet = editedCell.getSheet();

  //Number of headers on task sheet
  var noColumnHeaders = clientSheet.getRange("A4").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS).getValues()[0].length;
  //Entire row based on number of headers
  var completeRow = clientSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, noColumnHeaders).getValues();
  //Check if the row is completely filled 
  var isFilled = completeRow[0].indexOf("");

  if(isFilled == -1) {
    //Get master Spreadsheet
    var masterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[MASTER-SPREADSHEET-ID]");

    //Get master task sheet and set the values from client
    var masterSheet = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(clientSheet.getSheetName() + " master");
    masterSheet.getRange(masterSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, noColumnHeaders).setValues(completeRow);
  }
}

function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var clientSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[CLIENT-SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
  .forSpreadsheet(clientSpreadsheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```

You need to run createSpreadsheetEditTrigger function each time you want to add a client Spreadsheet (replacing first the given spreadsheet ID). Also, replace the master spreadsheet ID on myFunction.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

Comment: Thank you! that really helps!

Comment: Sure, I just did

Comment: Is there a way to get the script running with a simple onEdit trigger? I tried and it doesn’t seem to work

Comment: Sure, but you need to have the script bound to the Spreadsheet you're going to edit https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Thanks again Andres.
the functionallity is not possible with a simple trigger as I would have wanted, as these triggers don't have permission to modify other spreadsheets, as in this case.

This phases a different issue - these client spreadsheets are constantly updating by multiple users. Each user have to run the "createSpreadsheetEditTrigger" function that you have suggested. However- these are not tech savy users and I really rather they will not have any interaction with the code.

Comment: For now, the solution I found is adding a button to the spreadsheet that creates the onEdit installable trigger. However- This can't promiss all users will remember to do so before starting to update the spreadsheet. Moreover- the button can be clicked multiple times. Each click will create a duplicated, redundant trigger.

Comment: If you can think of a solution - I will be more than happy to hear it :)

Comment: If you're the owner of each Spreadsheet, you can run the `createSpreadsheetEditTrigger` yourself for each Spradsheet. The function will be triggered with your credentials when any of the user edit the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Oh, great. I thought each user needs to install the trigger locally for it to run.

Comment: If you can please accept the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).